# How to get information og orange/blue circle from StreetViewCoverageLayer

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    });
    var streetViewLayer= new google.maps.StreetViewCoverageLayer();
    streetViewLayer.setMap(map);

}
```

you can see some orange and blue circle on the map, it is about inside street view. how do I get information like name,position...... from those orange/blue circle?

you can see the orange/blue circle if you zoom in a city,those circle means inside view location,I just need to collect those inside view's information

https://jsfiddle.net/1tdg6fwm/1/

Comment: where is the blue/orange circle on your fiddle? I think you did not place it.

Comment: the orange circle is inside view look my update, thx